# Setting variables from a Key Value Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
array(
    'myVar1' => 'value1',
    'myVar2' => 'value1',
    'myVar3' => 'value3',
);
```

Is there a built in function in PHP that will make 3 variables e.g. $myVar1, $myVar2, $myVar3 do that when i `echo $myVar1;` it retuens `'value1'`

Obviously I can loop the array and set them accordingly (so please no answers with this), but if there is a internal PHP function that would be great!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[extract()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) is the function:

> Import variables into the current symbol table from an array...
>
> Checks each key to see whether it has a valid variable name. It also checks for collisions with existing variables in the symbol table...

Comment: Awesome. Didn't even know how I would search for this function.

Comment: @stereo bit more explanation would be awesome, under what circumstances?

Comment: Sure the explanation could be added. But the key purpose was to provide a PHP function that could do the job and I've mentioned the link to the PHP manual that explains it nicely; I left the implementation totally up to the implementer. I don't think using `extract()` is a bad practice, it's just you need to be sure what you are extracting. And then there are various extract types.

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array(
    'myVar1' => 'value1',
    'myVar2' => 'value1',
    'myVar3' => 'value3',
);

echo $array['myVar1'];
echo $array['myVar2'];
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think he means `$myVar1`, so he doesn't have to use `$array['myVar1']`